# VBA Report Header (Column Names) not showing on pages after page 1

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, report

I have a `VBA` report, that has a subform report that has a `Report Header` that displays the column names above the data.

All is well on page one, But one page two, the column names disappear.

Now i am not sure if this is because they are hidden behind another label or section or something? or if there is some setting that needs to be enabled.

Right now i have a `Event Procedure` on the `On Format` event on both the `Report Header` (column name locations) and the `Page Header`.  Neither of these worked.

The code for these `Event Procedures` follows:

```
Private Sub PageHeaderSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Me.ReportHeader.Visible = True
Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub ReportHeader_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
Me.ReportHeader.Visible = True
Me.PageHeaderSection.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable `Page Header/Footer` section? 
Right click on you form to get the context menu.

[image: Page Header/Footer]

**Form Header/Footer** - displayed only on first page. This is where you display your form/report name logo etc.

**Page Header/Footer** - displayed on each page. This is where you display column names, number of pages etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and i do have the page header and form header enabled.  The column headers are currently in the detail along with some other data that needs to be above the column/row data.  Is there a way i can put it in the page header and hide it on page one?  cause i dont want it above the other data on page one. and i cant move the other data into the page header as well because i dont want it to show up on every page

Comment: @jordan.peoples Just cut/paste. Why don't you want column headers on first page? That's unusual.

Comment: that doesnt work at all, even in the slightest.  anything i put into the page header will not show ever. and all the properties are set to true (the 'display ones')  and who said anything about column headers not on the first page. i said i dont want my header data (lets say for example, username and date and company name) on everypage...